# In VTK, is it possible to render a plot to an RGB buffer?

Tags: image, buffer, render, rgb, vtk

In VTK, is it possible to render a plot (something as simple as, say, the vtkChartXY example http://www.itk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx/Plotting/LinePlot) to an array of RGB values?

Answer (score 1):

The support is not currently present, but with some modification it would be possible to render into a pixel buffer object which may fit your requirement. You can already take a snapshot of the rendered image (and that is how the image based regression testing works), and save that as a PNG, or use the generated vktImageData for other things. I have been thinking about rendering some of these elements into PBOs so that they could then be used in textures etc.